# iterate through a nested list to get a specific value using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a json file where I'm trying to pull just "code" from multiple "areas"

I am able to pull the codes individually, but I feel like there should be a for loop I can write to iterate over every 'area' automatically as I won't always just have 3 areas.

I have tried multiple variations of the below nested loop but I just can't get it to iterate

```
for areas in data:
   for area in areas:
      print(area['code']
```

Current python code:

```
import json

with open('areas.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


    print(data['areas'][0]['area']['code'])
    print(data['areas'][1]['area']['code'])
    print(data['areas'][2]['area']['code'])
```

JSON file:

```
"areas": [
      {
         "slotId": "slot1",
         "area": {
            "id": "southern",
            "code": "southern",
            "label": "southern area",
            "featureToggles": [],
            "featureChoices": []
         },
         "editable": true,
         "areaCategoryId": null
      },
      {
         "slotId": "slot2",
         "area": {
            "id": "easter",
            "code": "eastern",
            "label": "eastern area",
            "featureToggles": [],
            "featureChoices": []
         },
         "editable": true,
         "areaCategoryId": null
      },
      {
         "slotId": "slot3",
         "area": {
            "id": "western",
            "code": "western",
            "label": "western area",
            "featureToggles": [],
            "featureChoices": []
         },
         "editable": true,
         "areaCategoryId": null
      }
```

The expected results is that the 'code' prints out for each area. Which it does correctly. However I want to iterate through it without having to add a new line every time as that's just ridiculous and tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access `data['areas']` which is a list, then iterate over it to get the individual `area` objects

```
with open('areas.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for area in data['areas']:
        print(area['area']['code'])
```

Comment: So I modified my code and now I'm getting a KeyError: 'area'. It states I'm getting it on line 8 which for me would be the above print statement

``` print(area['area']['code']) ```

Comment: According to your example, each of your objects are supposed to have `area` key in them. Perhaps, that is not the case?

Comment: The above code is correct, I had a typo on my end. Thanks for the help!